# setDate and maxDate combination jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

maxDate: 2.
minDate: 0,
setDate: 2019,09,06

I want the datepicker to select only September 7 and 8.

I tried using setDate and defaultDate but they only select the date.

In short: I want to select only 2 days ahead on the setDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
       minDate: new Date(2019,08,07) // Here month is 0 index based
       maxDate: new Date(2019,08,08) // // Here month is 0 index based
    });

});
```